# Unable to connect to terraform created AWS instance via ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, ssh, terraform

I am trying to use `terraform` to spin up a VPC and single instance and then connect via ssh but I'm unable to. I'm aware I don't have any keys here but I'm trying to simply connect via the web terminal and it still says

> There was a problem setting up the instance connection The connection
>   has been closed because the server is taking too long to respond. This
>   is usually caused by network problems, such as a spotty wireless
>   signal, or slow network speeds. Please check your network connection
>   and try again or contact your system administrator.

Is anyone able to look at my code and see what I'm doing wrong?

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-2"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
    cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
    enable_dns_hostnames = true
    enable_dns_support = true
    tags = {
        Name = "test"
    }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gateway" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"

    tags = {
        Name = "test"
    }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
    cidr_block = "${aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block}"
    availability_zone = "us-east-2a"
    map_public_ip_on_launch = true

    tags = {
        Name = "test"
    }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "table" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"

    route {
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
        gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.gateway.id}"
    }

    tags = {
        Name = "test"
    }

}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public" {
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.subnet.id}"
    route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.table.id}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "node" {
    #ami = "ami-0d5d9d301c853a04a" # Ubuntu 18.04
    ami = "ami-0d03add87774b12c5" # Ubuntu 16.04
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.subnet.id}"
}
```

**UPDATE1**: I've added `key_name = "mykey"` which I have previously created. I am unable to ping the public ip and upon trying to ssh with the key I get the following:

```
$ ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/mykey ubuntu@1.2.3.4
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 1.2.3.4 [1.2.3.4] port 22.
```

where `mykey` and `1.2.3.4` have been changed for posting.

**UPDATE2**: Looking at the security group I don't see anything which stands out. The ACL for this has the following:

```
Rule # Type          Protocol Port Range Source      Allow / Deny
100    ALL Traffic   ALL      ALL        0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW
*      ALL Traffic   ALL      ALL        0.0.0.0/0   DENY
```

Is this a problem? It seems that no one sees an issue with the terraform code so if anyone can confirm this is not a problem with the code then I think this can be closed out and moved to a different board since it would not be a code issue, correct?

Comment: ping the public ip of the instance first and then check the created sg rules. Most probably port 22 is blocked at the sg level or at the acl level in your given deployment. check those.

Comment: Pinging public ip didn't return anything.

Comment: and did you check the sgs and acl?

Comment: Sorry. Yes - I had checked sg previously and didn't see anything obvious, though I could be missing something. sg is default with all inbound traffic open on all ports. I had not previously looked at ACLs. This could be an issue. I'll update.

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question but is the internet gateway up? They do take a while to provision and I'm not sure if Terraform does it asynchronously. Double check the route tables as well.

Answer (score 1):

The web console uses SSH to connect, so you still need to setup an SSH key. The only way to connect without an SSH key configured, and port 22 open in the Security Group, is to use AWS Systems Manager Session Manager, but that requires the SSM agent running on the EC2 instance and appropriate IAM roles assigned to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have not supplied a [key_name](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#key_name) to indicate which SSH keypair to use.

If you don't have an existing [aws_key_pair](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/key_pair.html) then you will also need to create one.

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to connect via the web console with out a key name? I've experienced this same problem when using a key name but took this out to make the example minimal and reproducible.

Comment: Are you referring to EC2 Instance Connect? That requires some setup (see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-using-amazon-ec2-instance-connect-for-ssh-access-to-your-ec2-instances/)